# Can't Git Push Heroku Master Due To libv8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run git push heroku master I get this error the ruby race car installed fine and so did libv8 i have looked all over the internet and have yet to fix this problem any help would be great i am trying to push a local repo to heroku

```
doom@linux:~/rails_projects/first_app$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 68, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Writing objects: 100% (68/68), 26.16 KiB, done.
Total 68 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.2
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Installing rake (10.0.2)
   Installing i18n (0.6.1)
   Installing multi_json (1.5.0)
   Installing activesupport (3.2.9)
   Installing builder (3.0.4)
   Installing activemodel (3.2.9)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing journey (1.0.4)
   Installing rack (1.4.1)
   Installing rack-cache (1.2)
   Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
   Installing hike (1.2.1)
   Installing tilt (1.3.3)
   Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
   Installing actionpack (3.2.9)
   Installing mime-types (1.19)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
   Installing treetop (1.4.12)
   Installing mail (2.4.4)
   Installing actionmailer (3.2.9)
   Installing arel (3.0.2)
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.35)
   Installing activerecord (3.2.9)
   Installing activeresource (3.2.9)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
   Installing execjs (1.4.0)
   Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
   Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
   Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions
   Installing rdoc (3.12)
   Installing thor (0.16.0)
   Installing railties (3.2.9)
   Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
   Installing jquery-rails (2.0.2)
   Using bundler (1.2.2)
   Installing rails (3.2.9)
   Installing ref (1.0.2)
   Installing sass (3.2.3)
   Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
   Installing therubyracer (0.11.0) with native extensions
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
   checking for v8.h... no
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
   --with-pthreadlib
   --without-pthreadlib
   --enable-debug
   --disable-debug
   --with-v8-dir
   --without-v8-dir
   --with-v8-include
   --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
   --with-v8-lib
   --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
   /tmp/build_201rmwb3smm2n/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/build.rb:42:in `build_with_system_libv8': unable to locate libv8. Please see output for details (RuntimeError)
   from extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'
   The Ruby Racer requires libv8 ~> 3.11.8
   to be present on your system in order to compile
   and link, but it could not be found.
   In order to resolve this, you will either need to manually
   install an appropriate libv8 and make sure that this
   build process can find it. If you install it into the
   standard system path, then it should just be picked up
   automatically. Otherwise, you'll have to pass some extra
   flags to the build process as a hint.
   If you don't want to bother with all that, there is a
   rubygem that will do all this for you. You can add
   following line to your Gemfile:
   gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'
   We hope that helps, and we apologize, but now we have
   to push the eject button on this install.
   thanks,
   The Mgmt.
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_201rmwb3smm2n/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_201rmwb3smm2n/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

 To git@heroku.com:still-tundra-4364.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:still-tundra-4364.git'
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

    group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'
    #gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'  # Update version number as needed
    gem "execjs", "~> 1.4.0"
    gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.11.0beta5'
    end


    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
    #gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'

    gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

    group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
    end
```

And My Gemlock file

```
GEM
remote: https://rubygems.org/
specs:
actionmailer (3.2.9)
  actionpack (= 3.2.9)
  mail (~> 2.4.4)
actionpack (3.2.9)
  activemodel (= 3.2.9)
  activesupport (= 3.2.9)
  builder (~> 3.0.0)
  erubis (~> 2.7.0)
  journey (~> 1.0.4)
  rack (~> 1.4.0)
  rack-cache (~> 1.2)
  rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
  sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
activemodel (3.2.9)
  activesupport (= 3.2.9)
  builder (~> 3.0.0)
activerecord (3.2.9)
  activemodel (= 3.2.9)
  activesupport (= 3.2.9)
  arel (~> 3.0.2)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
activeresource (3.2.9)
  activemodel (= 3.2.9)
  activesupport (= 3.2.9)
activesupport (3.2.9)
  i18n (~> 0.6)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
  railties (~> 3.2.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
  coffee-script-source
  execjs
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
  thor (~> 0.14)
json (1.7.5)
libv8 (3.11.8.4)
mail (2.4.4)
  i18n (>= 0.4.0)
  mime-types (~> 1.16)
  treetop (~> 1.4.8)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.5.0)
pg (0.12.2)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
  rack (>= 0.4)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  rack
rack-test (0.6.2)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rails (3.2.9)
  actionmailer (= 3.2.9)
  actionpack (= 3.2.9)
  activerecord (= 3.2.9)
  activeresource (= 3.2.9)
  activesupport (= 3.2.9)
  bundler (~> 1.0)
  railties (= 3.2.9)
railties (3.2.9)
  actionpack (= 3.2.9)
  activesupport (= 3.2.9)
  rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  rdoc (~> 3.4)
  thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
rake (10.0.2)
rdoc (3.12)
  json (~> 1.4)
ref (1.0.2)
sass (3.2.3)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
  railties (~> 3.2.0)
  sass (>= 3.1.10)
  tilt (~> 1.3)
sprockets (2.2.2)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.5)
therubyracer (0.11.0)
  ref
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
  polyglot
  polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.2.3)
  execjs (>= 0.3.0)
  multi_json (>= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
ruby

DEPENDENCIES
coffee-rails (= 3.2.2)
execjs (~> 1.4.0)
jquery-rails (= 2.0.2)
libv8 (~> 3.11.8)
pg (= 0.12.2)
rails (= 3.2.9)
sass-rails (= 3.2.5)
sqlite3 (= 1.3.5)
therubyracer (~> 0.11.0beta5)
uglifier (= 1.2.3)
```

So it seems that there is now a known problem that has no work around that i know of

https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/215

Comment: @PinnyM: I think it's a different problem. Try reading the given URL.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and tried one of the suggestions (use the known working `therubyracer`):

```
# Gemfile
gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2', :platforms => :ruby
```

That's it. I can deploy to Heroku again.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to include therubyracer et.al. any more.

from: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

> therubyracer
>
> If you were previously using therubyracer or therubyracer-heroku,
>   these gems are no longer required and strongly discouraged as these
>   gems use a very large amount of memory.